# Getting Bigger Factor from Smaller Factor

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I have a little confusion. In an [article entitled "Torsion Points of Elliptic Curves" (page 15)](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Galperin.pdf),it is written that-

> From our equation for the line through $P_1$ and $P_2$, we know that
>   $s_1 = αt_1 + β$. Because $s_1 \in p^{v}R_p$, we know that 
>   $s_1 \in p^{3v}R_p$. And, because $α \in  p^{2v}R_p$ and $t_1 \in  p^vR_p$, we
>   have that $αt_1 \in  p^{3v}R_p$. Therefore, the equation for the line
>   gives us that $β \in  p^{3v}R_p$.

I don't understand -

> Because $s_1 \in p^{v}R_p$, we know that  $s_1 \in p^{3v}R_p$.

How one concludes  $s_1 \in p^{3v}R_p$ from  $s_1 \in p^{v}R_p$?

We can say/infer $s_1 \in p^{v}R_p$ from   $s_1 \in p^{3v}R_p$ not the other way around, then why author wrote

> Because $s_1 \in p^{v}R_p$, we know that  $s_1 \in p^{3v}R_p$. 
>   ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a poor phrasing on the author's part. It would make more sense to say

"Since $(t_1,s_1)\in E(p^\nu)$, then $s_1\in p^{3\nu}R_p$"

They establish at the bottom of page 13 that we must have $t\in p^\nu R_p$ and $s\in p^{3\nu}R_p$ for any $(t,s)$ on the curve, this following from the defining equation of E.